# How to find the shortest sequence of asterisks separating two distinct letters in a string using STL algorithms?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I have a string like this:

`A*A**B***A**`

I'm interested in sequences of asterisks that are between two distinct letters, in particular I need to find the length of the shortest such sequence. For the above string the answer is, of course, 2: `A**B`

I can easily solve this problem using a traditional loop, the likes of which I'm accustomed to:

```
const string s = "A*A**B***A**";
string::size_type last_letter=-1, min_seq_len=s.size();
for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
    if(last_letter == -1 || s[i] == '*' || s[i] == s[last_letter]) {
        if(s[i] != '*') {
            last_letter = i;
        }
    } else {
        min_seq_len = min(min_seq_len, i-last_letter-1);
        last_letter = i;
    }
}
```

However, is there any way to do this using the C++ [algorithms library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm), iterators etc?

I'm asking this question because I've noticed I have trouble learning how to use these facilities to solve algorithmic problems and instead I find writing loops by hand easier. And I'd like to finally learn operating on C++ algorithms, ranges, iterators etc.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm interested in sequences of asterisks that are between two distinct letters, in particular I need to find the length of the shortest such sequence.

1. You need to minimize something. You can use `std::min_element` for that.
2. That something is a bunch of "letter+asterisks+letter" chunks. You can find non-asterisks by using `std::find_if`.

You then need to write some glue between the algorithms, that you can hide behind an STL-like interface. Example:

```
auto letter_pairs = letter_pair_generator(s);
const auto min_seq_len = std::min_element(
    std::begin(letter_pairs), std::end(letter_pairs),
    [](const auto& x) { return x.asterisk_count(); });
```

Where `letter_pair_generator` is an adapter over an `std::string` that exposes a container-like interface which returns pairs of distinct letters with asterisks in between. Example:

```
string s = "A*A**B***A**";
for(const auto& p : letter_pair_generator(s)) cout << p;
```

> A*A**B
>
> A**B
>
> A**B***A
>
> B***A

---

> instead I find writing loops by hand easier

Sometimes a loop is clearer and faster than multiple calls to `<algorithm>`. There's nothing inherently wrong with that. Use a loop and wrap it into a safer/nicer interface.

Comment: Re, _a bunch of "letter+asterisks+letter" chunks_:  Be careful there because one letter can be part of two different "chunks".

Answer (score 0):

I need to say that I couldn't get a huge improvement with the use of the standard library. But for example `std::regex` example would be much simpler if there were no distinct letters requirement. Anyway here is my attempts.

1. `std::string::find_first_not_of` usage

   ```
   int best = s.size();
   int prev = -1;
   int next;

   while ((next = s.find_first_not_of("*", prev+1)) >= 0) {
       if (prev >= 0 && s[prev] != s[next]) {
           best = min(best, next - prev - 1);              
       }
       prev = next;
   }
   ```

Runnable: https://ideone.com/xdhiQt

2. `std::regex` usage:

   ```
   regex r("(?=([^*][*]*[^*]))");

   int best = s.size();
   for (auto i = sregex_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), r); i != sregex_iterator(); ++i) {
       int pos = i->position(1);
       int len = i->length(1); 
       if (s[pos] != s[pos + len -1]) {
           best = min(len-2, best);
       }
   }
   ```

Runnable: https://ideone.com/2UdRGG

Answer (score 0):

You may use `find_first_not_of` of `string` for this, too.

```cpp
size_t min(str.length()), prev(0), found(0);
while((found = str.find_first_not_of("*", prev)) != std::string::npos) {
  if (str[found] != str[prev] && found - prev < min) {
    min = found + 1 - prev;
  }
  prev = found + 1;
}
```

[demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1c20bd9bd8e73af3)